# With capitalization, what are null, true, and false literals in Django templating if tags?

Tags: django-templates

With capitalization, what are the Django templating language literals for true, false, and null?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it should be True, False and None.

Comment: Thank you. Those are the Python language literals. I want to know what they are for [the Django templating language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/).

Comment: Yes, it is same.